# Search for null field in Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, t-sql

Using T-SQL in SQL Server Management Studio this query returns exactly what I am expecting

```
SELECT * FROM ZipCodeTerritory WHERE ZipCode IS NULL and StateCode = 'WA'
```

However... the following Linq query returns no results. I've checked the connection string and I have verified I'm connecting to the database. Using a value for the `cleanZip` variable will return a list. Using a null value, however, never returns anything.

```
string cleanZip = (item.ToUpper().Equals("NULL") ? null : item.Trim());

var zipCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                where z.ZipCode.Equals(cleanZip) && z.StateCode.Equals(searchState)
                select z).ToList();
```

Comment: Try using `where z.ZipCode equals cleanZip && z.StateCode equals searchState`

I am unsure if `.Equals()` works where you have put it. You could also try `==` instead. Edit: `equals` will not work here, only in joins.

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before (if i understand you correctly). Just tried typing it into Visual Studio and the intellisense doesn't recognize it/throws an exception.

Comment: It looks like `equals` is only for joins, did you try `==`?

Comment: Yeah, no luck with `==`

Comment: `==` will work if the `ZipCode` has a defined value, but not for `null`. Similar to how `.Equals()` is responding

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with your `string cleanZip`? I wonder if you need to do a check like `|| z.ZipCode.Equals(string.Empty)` because of some LINQ magic I don't understand?

Comment: Try looking at this: http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/04/checking_for_possibly_null_values_in_linq.html
and look at the example on the very bottom.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Changed the query to the following and it is working now.

```
var zipCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                where (cleanZip == null ? z.ZipCode.Equals(null) : z.ZipCode.Equals(cleanZip)) && z.StateCode.Equals(searchState)
                select z).ToList();
```